# Distributing width of css class only to selected column where width is in both '%' and 'px'

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a css class in which width attribute is set in both percentage and pixel. for example

```
 .v_sn{width:43px;}
 .v_comp{width:5%; display:none !important;}
 .v_sts{width:67px;}
 .v_no{width:120px;}
 .v_ign{width:19px; cursor:default;}
 .v_pwr{width:25px; cursor:default;}
 .v_ac{width:15px; cursor:default;}
 .v_gps{width:22px; cursor:default;}
 .v_dura{width:82px;}
 .v_spd{width:68px;}
 .v_loc{width:24%;}
 .v_poi{width:24%;}
 .v_info{width:3%; cursor:default;}
 .v_path{width:3%; cursor:default;}
```

I have used this class to set width of the table's columns.

What i want is when i hide a column by clicking on column, width of that column should be distributed to only specific column.
In my case I only want to distribute that width(Width of hidden column) in column having class ".v_no",".v_loc" and ".v_poi".

Comment: How does a column get hidden? Does it get an extra class? If so, you can use the class as an extra selector for the other classes, provided they are after the hidden column in the DOM tree.

Comment: Atcually I am having a project in which i have used checkbox for hiding column.So, Unchecked column are hidden with .hide() function. And It does not get any extra class. I want to use the width of hidden class and distribute width only to three column of my table.

Comment: You mean you can hide any of the columns? That would be cumbersome. I assumed there was only one column you needed to hide. In this example, `.v_comp`, so the other three columns would gain another 1.666% each. I don't think this is as straightforward. Sorry.

Comment: No. Checkbox i have provided to hide column is not having choice of two column of table so. those two column will always be there.